# Drawer to bottom nav bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

I originally had a hamburger bar that opened a drawer to navigate between pages and I am wanting to change this to a bottom nav bar but I am struggling a bit. This is the code for the bottom nav bar:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have all the code for my main page in a class like this:

```
class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstRoute({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _FirstRoute createState() => _FirstRoute();
}

class _FirstRoute extends State<FirstRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

And I don't understand how to put this into the Widget section in the bottom nav bar where the `Text()` section is.
I am new to using Flutter so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have todo here is to replace the text widgets with your widgets/screens

example

```
static  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    FirstRoute(),
    SecondRoute(),
    ThirdRoute(),    
  ];
```

Comment: Hi this works so long as you remove the ```const```, thank you!!